# How to trigger a jquery function from a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have individual checkbox jquery functions to hide/show columns.

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function () {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
```

I also have a select/unselect all jquery:

```
$('#select_all').click(function (event) {
if (this.checked) {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $(':checkbox').each(function () {
        this.checked = true;
        this.trigger("click");//this doesn't work
    });
}
else {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $(":checkbox").each(function () {
        this.checked = false;
        this.trigger("click");//this doesn't work either
    });
}
});
```

How can I trigger the click function from inside the select all click functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate functions

```
function hideColumn(obj){
    var column = "table ." + obj.attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
}

function showColumn(obj){
    var column = "table ." + obj.attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
}
```

And your code would be:

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function () {
    hideColumn($(this));
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    showColumn($(this));
});
```

To (un)select all:

```
$('#select_all').click(function (event) {
if (this.checked) {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $(':checkbox').each(function () {
        this.checked = true;
        hideColumn($(this));
    });
}
else {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $(":checkbox").each(function () {
        this.checked = false;
        showColumn($(this));
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to change 'this' in js to 'obj' since it is an keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the javascript DOM object. You need a jQuery object for trigger: `$(this).trigger('click');`.